# Disk manager unable to delete a partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

There is a SD card attached to my laptop. When I open the disk manager, I see that the removable disk is partitioned into two parts. One is FAT32 and the other is unallocated. The problem is that I am not able to delete the fat32 partition as shown in the picture. Any idea to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Try to full format it.

Comment: The question is how? since there is not "format" or "delete" in the menu.

Comment: Right click on the SD card in explorer an format from there.